# Incorrect Aspect Ratio for Games using nVidia Surround

Tags: pc, hardware

I am trying to configure any game within Steam, either Call of Duty Black Ops, Modern Warfare 3,  or Fallout New Vegas, to correctly use my surround setup of three monitors. Problem is, the single-screen image gets stretched across the three monitors rather than getting more field of view on the two side screens. Is there something I'm missing either when configuring the video card or the game?

My hardware:

- One EVGA GTX 660 Card.
- Three Hanns 28" HZ281 monitors plugged in, two to the DVI ports, one to the HDMI.